# Use replace with interval in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show if 0 it will put a word, perm for example and if not 0 it will get the normal date using interval.

Tried to include it in replace.

`REPLACE(REPLACE(usetime,0,'PERM'), add_time + interval usetime minute)`

If usetime = 0

```
START DATE            USETIME     END DATE
--------------------------------------------
2019-04-11 23:01:11     0           PERM
```

If usetime is not 0 and is something else(not a specific value)

```
START DATE            USETIME     END DATE
--------------------------------------------
2019-04-11 23:01:11     5         2019-04-11 23:06:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `REPLACE()`, use `CASE`:

```
(CASE WHEN usetime = 0 THEN 'PERM'
      ELSE add_time + interval usetime minute
 END)
```

You might want to use `date_format()` to format the date to a string with exactly the format you want.